# Symbolic integration vs numeric integration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an expression with three variables x,y and v.  I want to first integrate over v, and so I use int function in MATLAB.

[image]

The command that I use is the following:

```
g =int((1-fxyz)*pv, v, y,+inf)%
```

PS I haven't given you what the function fxyv is but it is very complicated and so int is taking so long and I am afraid after waiting it might not solve it.

I know one option for me is to integrate numerically using for example integrate, however I want to note that the second part of this problem requires me to integrate exp[g(x,y)] over x and y from 0 to infinity and from x to infinity respectively. So I can't take  numerical values of x and y when I want to integrate over v I think or maybe not ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a triple integral. You can this numerically with `integral3`. Regarding your question about symbolic integration, if the issue is your integrand is complicated, then you should edit your question to provide runnable code so that we have a chance of helping you.

Comment: @horchler I will edit the question to show you why I haven't used the triple integral. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @horchler I don't have a problem with how int or integral works in MATLAB, I am looking for help  in finding the best way to do it. that is why I havent included the functions . Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your formula, you have a function g with one and two parameters at the same time.

Comment: wait sorry for the notation I will edit. @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel I dont think numerical integration is the right choice for me right?

Comment: @George: I think both using `symbolic\int` and `integral3` should be possible. Try it and if you experience any problems describe the problem in a way we can reproduce it.

Comment: @Daniel how can integral3 be used, I don't think  we can do it because of the exp function, can you please write one command using the function I provided above?

Comment: There is no definition of the functions `f` and `p`? There is no way to tell whether this can be integrated analytically without that.

Comment: @A.Donda suppose that int isn't working.. What is my alternative for such a function?

Comment: Numeric integration should always be possible. Other than that, it is hard to say anything without more detail. Can you give an example of the functions `f` and `p`?

Comment: I dont feel like i can write the above with numerical integral? Do you mean integral3? If yes, how would you write it? @A.Donda.. Belive me the function is very hard ... If you can just write how would you proceed with numerical integraion in terms of the notations i provided above it would be great

Comment: Notice that if I want to solve the first integral numerically I would have to take numerical values of x,y? Then how would you use the result to compute the second integral (knowing that you already have taken values of x and y to solve the first) @A.Donda

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Hang on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question does not contain sufficient detail to attempt analytic integration, this answer focuses on numeric integration.

It is possible to solve these equations numerically. However, because of complex dependencies between the three integrals, it is not possible to simply use `integral3`. Instead, one has to define functions that compute parts of the expressions using a simple `integral`, and are themselves fed into other calls of `integral`. Whether this approach leads to useful results in terms of computation time and precision cannot be answered generally, but depends on the concrete choice of the functions `f` and `p`. Fiddling around with precision parameters to the different calls of `integral` may be necessary.

I assume that the functions f(x, y, v) and p(v) are defined in the form of Matlab functions:

```
function val = f(x, y, v)
val = ...
end

function val = p(v)
val = ...
end
```

Because of the way they are used later, they have to accept multiple values for `v` in parallel (as an array) and return as many function values (again as an array, of the same size). `x` and `y` can be assumed to always be scalars. A simple example implementation would be `val = ones(size(v))` in both cases.

First, let's define a Matlab function `g` that implements the first equation:

```
function val = g(x, y)
val = integral(@gIntegrand, y, inf);

    function val = gIntegrand(v)
        % output must be of the same dimensions as parameter v
        val = (1 - f(x, y, v)) .* p(v);
    end
end
```

The nested function `gIntegrand` defines the object of integration, the outer performs the numeric integration that gives the value of g(x, y). Integration is over v, parameters x and y are shared between the outer and the nested function. `gIntegrand` is written in such a way that it deals with multiple values of v in the form of arrays, provided `f` and `p` do so already.

Next, we define the integrand of the outer integral in the second equation. To do so, we need to compute the inner integral, and therefore also have a function for the integrand of the inner integral:

```
function val = TIntegrandOuter(x)
val = nan(size(x));
for i = 1 : numel(x)
    val(i) = integral(@TIntegrandInner, x(i), inf);
end

    function val = TIntegrandInner(y)
        val = nan(size(y));
        for j = 1 : numel(y)
            val(j) = exp(g(x(i), y(j)));
        end
    end
end
```

Because both function are meant to be fed as an argument into `integral`, they need to be able to deal with multiple values. In this case, this is implemented via an explicit for loop. `TIntegrandInner` computes exp(g(x, y)) for multiple values of y, but the fixed value of x that is current in the loop in `TIntegrandOuter`. This value `x(i)` play both the role of a parameter into g(x, y) and of an integration limit. Variables `x` and `i` are shared between the outer and the nested function.

Almost there! We have the integrand, only the outermost integration needs to be performed:

```
T = integral(@TIntegrandOuter, 0, inf);
```

This is a very convoluted implementation, which is not very elegant, and probably not very efficient. Again, whether results of this approach prove to be useful needs to be tested in practice. However, I don't see any other way to implement these numeric integrations in Matlab in a better way in general. For specific choices of f(x, y, v) and p(v), there might be possible improvements.

Comment: x and y in the second integral take on values to +infinity. How can you numerically take values of them to compute your first integral.?

Comment: @George, I don't know how that is implemented within `integral`, I just use this functionality. See the first example in the documentation, "Improper Integral": http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html